# How do i stop apps i dont want or use from redownloading?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-3

Apps like Google Books and Flipaclip I dont use them so I Uninstal them but the moment I turn my Samsung Galaxy back on they redownload taking up space for app I do want/use in the future so how can I stop this if it is even possible D: please help?! TT^TT

Comment: Are those system apps? Are you pressing "uninstall" or are you just clearing data?

Answer (score 3):

If they are system apps, then you're probably not uninstalling them, you're just uninstalling the previous updates. And probably your automatic update is turned on in Play store , and hence why whenever you boot up your phone and it gets internet access, it starts to download the available updates (which includes the apps you don't use/want). So go over to play store and disable automatic updates, or you can find the app (that you don't want to receive updates for), and disable automatic update by unchecking the option in your top-right corner. But if you want to get rid of those apps completely then you'll have to root your phone (only if those are system apps), and remove them afterwards, or you can just disable those apps (which don't require rooting) in settings if there is an option....